# QueryDict always empty from AJAX POST

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I have seen a few of these questions asked but I have tried to implement their solutions and it hasn't worked for me.

I am trying to send a basic AJAX request to a django view using POST. Here is my JQuery:

```
$('#save-button').click(function() {
    var names = ['BLOGGS Joe', 'SMITH John'];
    data = JSON.stringify(names);
    $.ajax({
        "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "data": data,
        "url" : "/ajax/myteam/save/",
        "type": "POST",
        "success": function(response) {

        }
    });
});
```

And here is my Django view:

```
def myteam_save(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
       if request.POST:
           print 'Hurray'
       else:
           print 'Boo'
       response = HttpResponse(json.dumps({'code':'ok'}), content_type='application/json')
       return response
```

When I examine whats happening in Firebug I see that the post is being made as I intend but the QueryDict object from request.POST is always empty.

I have been careful about csrf tokens I think and even tried turning off the 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' in my settings but this appears to have no effect.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `"contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8"` you are not sending JSON to the server. Also, it should be `dataType:'json'` to tell the `success function` to treat the `response` as a parseable JSON object. As far as the django response is concerned...access the page directly, debug until you get output, validate the output is indeed json.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy thanks for response. The content type was just me trying to match someone else code to fix problem and forgot to change back. What do you mean by access the page directly (sorry if stupid question)?

Answer (score 16):

`Django` doesn't really de-serialize `JSON` payloads for you. `request.POST` is meant to be used for HTML posted forms, and the like.

For `JSON` payloads, you should de-serialize the request body yourself, for example: `json.loads(request.body)`.

(`request.body` is how you access the raw payload).

Answer (score 5):

As @Sergio told, you need to decode the `request.body` in you views.py. This is the solution by using `Django 3.1` and `Fetch`.

```
def myteam_save(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.headers.get("contentType": "application/json"):
        body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
        received_json = json.loads(body_unicode)

    return JsonResponse(received_json, safe=False)
```

I am not familiar with `AJAX`. So I post how typical `POST` with `XHR` should be using `Fetch`. Assuming `varKey` and `varValue` is pre-defined variables with value to send as json:

According to [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/csrf/#ajax) you have to pass it for security reasons.

```
function getCookie(name) {
    let cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
```

Below is actual `XHR` done by using `Fetch`:

```
dict = { [varKey]: varValue }

fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/bot/api/post/45/", {
    headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
        "x-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(dict),
    mode: 'same-origin',
})
```