# Ajax post data not showing in Django view POST

Tags: python, ajax, json, django

I know this has been asked many times before, I've looked at all of the previous answer, yet django and ajax defies me. Common problem, data I'm sending via ajax post is not showing up in my request in my view, `POST` is always empty. Everything else works, calling view, returning json.

I've tried all of the answers and it still won't work, maybe I'm missing something small. Side note: I've disabled csrf for django since I don't need it.

Ajax:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ping_device',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { 'port': '20' },
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            success: function (result) {
                debugger;
                alert("message: " + result.message);
            },
            error: function(data){
                alert('error..');
            }
        })
```

view:

```
def ping_device(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        test = request.POST.get('port', 'ffs')

        message = "this is a post"
        response_data = {}
        response_data["message"] = message

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

**EDIT** my settings.py:
"""

```
Django settings for BACnetModbus_WebApp project.
"""

from os import path
PROJECT_ROOT = path.dirname(path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__)))

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ALLOWED_HOSTS = (
    'localhost',
)

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

#DATABASES = {
#    'default': {
#        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
#        'NAME': path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'db.sqlite3'),
#        'USER': '',
#        'PASSWORD': '',
#        'HOST': '',
#        'PORT': '',
#    }
#}

LOGIN_URL = '/login'

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
# timezone as the operating system.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static').replace('\\', '/')

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'n(bd1f1c%e8=_xad02x5qtfn%wgwpi492e$8_erx+d)!tpeoim'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

#MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    #'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    #'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    #'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    #'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
#)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'BACnetModbus_WebApp.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'BACnetModbus_WebApp.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or
    # "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app',
    'bootstrap3',
    'pymodbus',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}

# Specify the default test runner.
TEST_RUNNER = 'django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'
```

Comment: Just curious, if you remove `contentType` line in your `ajax` call, what would happen?

Comment: nothing, still does the same thing. I think I read somewhere that jquery by default has contentType set to what I have.

Comment: What is the URL pattern for the `ping_device` view? Does it have a trailing slash? What do you get if you print `request.body`?

Comment: Try removing quotes from port in script, i.e. data: {port: '20'}

Comment: `url(r'^ping_device', 'app.views.ping_device', name='ping_device'),` is my url. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25791913/querydict-always-empty-from-ajax-post tried to see if maybe this was it but then i get a `cannot access body after reading from request's data stream` error

Comment: Maybe change your url line to `url: '{% url "ping_device" %}'`?

Comment: @SaurabhGoyal  I tried it and still teh same problem, POST is empty in the view

Comment: The URL looks ok. Try printing `request.body` **before** accessing `request.POST` to prevent the ’cannot access body’ error. If you still get that error, maybe you have some custom middleware?

Comment: my url is `http://localhost:61664/pring_device`, when I try and run `request.POST` I get the error : `RawPostDataException("You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream") 403 forbidden`

Comment: @Alasdair that's what I was thinking too, but I think i disabled it all in my settings

Comment: Make sure you have disabled the middleware and restarted the server afterwards.

Comment: I'll post my settings. I have disabled everything and I have restarted the server

Answer (score 0):

Add a line dataType: 'json' to your ajax call.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ping_device',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 'port': '20' },
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        dataType: 'json',   // type of data expected back from the server
        success: function (result) {
            debugger;
            alert("message: " + result.message);
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert('error..');
        }
    })
```

Comment: still gives me 403 forbidden