# Get data in Django view from AJAX POST request

Tags: javascript, python, django, python-3.x, ajax

I am new to Django and working on a project which does not involve the use of forms in Django. I have a JS which makes an AJAX POST call to my Django web service which is my backend and I just want a response from it.
However I always get none on doing so. I searched a lot but was not able to find a solution. Here is my code:

My project `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', include('demo_app.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

My app `urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('dispatcher/', views.dispatcher, name='dispatcher'),
]
```

My `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from demo_app.models import VesselStatus
from django.db.models import Count
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world")

@csrf_exempt
def dispatcher(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.POST.get("inputText"))
        return HttpResponse(request)
```

I dont want to use forms hence the CSRF exempt decorator

My AJAX call:

```
if(individual_result.toLowerCase().includes('some text'))
    {
      console.log("Found");
      data = {
        "inputText": individual_result
      }
      $.ajax
      ({
        crossDomain: true,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url:"--address-of-local--/home/dispatcher/",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
          console.log(response)
        }
      })
    }
```

For some reason I always seem to get null. Dont know what is the issue

Comment: Did you try printing `request.POST`? Did you see what the request's body looks like in a browser's developer tools?

Comment: @schillingt I get an empty dict :(

Answer (score 1):

I got it. For requests that are sent other than from a HTML form, as in like my case through an AJAX call, it HAS to be accessed using `request.body` ONLY

Thanks to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30879038/12806725