# getting empty dictionary on POST ajax

Tags: django, ajax, django-views

I am trying to delete some elements in database when user clicks on delete icon but as i am sending id through *POST* request , i am getting *empty dictionary* ,

```
{% for skills in seeker_skills %}
           <div class="col-md-4">
            <button class="btn btn-info mx-2">{{skills.skill_name}}<span class="badge badge-dark ">{{skills.skill_level}}</span></button><span><i class="fas fa-trash-alt delete_skill" data-attr={{skills.id}} style="cursor: pointer;"></i></span>
           </div>
           {% endfor %}
```

updated snippet , i am calling it on click
**Ajax code**

```
let delete_class_list = $('.delete_skill')
delete_class_list.click(function(e){
    let value = this.getAttribute("data-attr")
    let contain_icon = this
    let contain_label = contain_icon.parentElement.previousSibling
    console.log(contain_label)
    $.ajax({
        url:'/delete_skill/',
        method : 'POST',
        data: {
            skill_id:value
        },
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success :function(data){
            console.log(data)
            contain_label.remove()
            contain_icon.remove()   
        }
        ,
        error:function(e){
            console.log(e)

        }
    })
})
```

**My view**

```
@csrf_exempt
def delete_skill(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = {}
        print('method is post')
        job_id = request.POST.get('skill_id')
        print(job_id)
        try:
            Job_Skillset.objects.get(id=job_id).delete()
            data['status'] = 'deleted'
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            data['status'] = 'nodata'
        return JsonResponse(data,safe=False)
```

Comment: Have you got a value for `job_id` in your backend console ?

Comment: @Rvector its showing `None`

Comment: are you calling this on click ?

Comment: yes  @amadousow on click event handler i updated by code

Comment: If `job_id` is `None` then `request.POST.get('skill_id')` is `None`, the data is not sended as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting your content type to `application/json` which is incorrect, remove it.

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/delete_skill/',
    method : 'POST',
    data: {
        skill_id:value
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success :function(data){
        console.log(data)
        contain_label.remove()
        contain_icon.remove()   
    }
    ,
    error:function(e){
        console.log(e)

    }
})
```

Comment: i am still getting `None`  `[26/Sep/2021 22:08:27] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 7459
None`

Comment: That's not the same request. Its the favicon request most browsers make. The request is a `POST` and was to `/delete_skill/` .

Comment: I am applying the same logic to the different view as well, same sending data via `POST` but no avail is there any prob with my HTML snip,

Comment: thankyou, I was having trouble understanding but both your answer and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25791913/querydict-always-empty-from-ajax-post helped me